# A way to describe my interest in getting to know people's stories

Tags: phrase-requests

I want to be able to phrase the interest I have in meeting new people and talking to them about their life stories and experiences.

It is a level deeper than just an extrovert, who would be someone who likes to meet new people. I like getting to know them better.

Though it's also not someone who likes to make a lot of friends. Just meeting people, have great conversations, and move on ahead.

It is for an application of sorts and I want to be able to mention this specific interest I have.

Comment: you might like https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com

Comment: You want to *connect with* people?  // Show a sample sentence, and explain more about what you want and why.  (Don't bother with explaining who you aren't or what you don't want.)

Answer (score 1):

Social, friendly, empatic, I would say

Comment: how does 'i would say' answer the question?

Comment: @JohnMark about as good as claiming "The word you are looking for here is..." from another answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for here is *empathy*

The quality of being able to hear out another person, and not just because it makes them feel better, but because you love doing it; that's empathy. The person is then said to be empathetic in nature.

> An empathetic person is someone who can share another person's feelings. If you tell an empathetic person that your heart is broken, she might touch her own heart and gaze at you sadly through moist eyes.

"Empathetic is a recent term; it comes from empathy, which was coined by the German philosopher Rudolf Lotze in 1858. Lotze believed that when you look at a work of art, you project your own sensibilities onto it. So if you feel sad when you see a painting of a woman weeping over a dying lover, that's because you can imagine what it's like to lose someone you love."...*[Reference](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/empathetic)*

Comment: I think that's the closest answer. Being empathetic would then be who I am rather than what I like to do. I think it is more of a quality then, rather than an interest or hobby.